# Update the last before last schema, does it need to rollback to the that migrations?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

My migration status is follows:

```
macbook:mirror yuchen$ mix ecto.migrations -r Mirror.Repo

Repo: Mirror.Repo

  Status    Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
  up        20221011000915  create_importers
  up        20221011120109  create_products
  up        20221011233005  create_pictures
```

I have updated '20221011120109_create_products.exs' file by adding one fields.

```
defmodule Mirror.Repo.Migrations.CreateProducts do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:products) do
      add :importer_id, :string # newly added field
      add :title, :string
      add :cid, :string
      add :seller_cids, :string
```

Is it possible to save the test data and update schema.

In addtion, is it possible to update 'create_products' directly and rollback 'create_pictures'?

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly how migrations are supposed to be used. Instead of amending the already applied migration, you should create the new one, [modifying the column](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#add/3-examples), like:

```elixir
alter table(:products) do
  add :importer_id, :string # newly added field
end
```

---

But you still can apply migrations manually with a help of [`Ecto.Migrator`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migrator.html#module-example-running-an-individual-migration).

Comment: Create the new one,  doesn't it mean to copy "20221011120109_create_products.exs" file then rename it and add the above `alter` statement?

Comment: Nothing to copy. The timestamp matters for the order of migrations application. Run [`mix ecto.gen.migration alter_products_table_add_importer`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Mix.Tasks.Ecto.Gen.Migration.html) and then edit it to contain `def change do [ALTER STATEMENT] end`.

Comment: Also, if you haven't deployed it yet and it is just your local environment, it is perfectly fine to edit a migration file while you're still working on it. You can rollback and re-run it, or just run `mix ecto.reset` and possibly `MIX_ENV=test mix ecto.reset` to start from a clean slate on your dev and test databases at any point. Dropping the data isn't a concern if you're using seeds.